# Using PatternSequence on its own in ReplaceAll?

Tags: replacement

Say I have this list:

```
list = {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 4}
```

and say I want to remove consecutive sequences of 0 and 1. 
I'd normally go for this:

```
list //. {before___, 0, 1, after___} :> {before, after}
```

> ```
> {2,3,4}
> ```

But a more concise way would be the following:

```
list /. PatternSequence[0, 1] -> Sequence[]
```

Alas, this doesn't do anything. The examples in the `PatternSequence` documentation are all of the form

```
list //. {before___, PatternSequence[0, 1], after___} :> {before, after}
```

which kind of defeat the purpose. (It's pretty useful if you want to *name* the `PatternSequence` on the LHS of the rule, but that's not my aim).

So the question is, is there a way to use constructs like `PatternSequence[0, 1] -> Sequence[]` in `ReplaceAll`?

Comment: My impression so far has been that the main advantage of `PatternSequence`is that now one can name sequences of patterns for restructuring. This is an important feature, but is not the same as what you are looking for.

Comment: Related Q: why does `list //. {before___, 0, 1, after___} :> after` only match the first instance? Whereas, `{a, b, a} //. a :> z` matches both instances of `a`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do what you are trying to, unfortunately.

As Leonid says, `PatternSequence` is for grouping purposes. And in general the WL pattern matcher is not geared for "sequence-based patterns" for a whole variety of reasons. At a fundamental level the pattern matcher uses a 'cursor' that is always rooted at the level of an entire expression, and sequences are matched *within* that expression, rather than the 'cursor' itself being a sequence.

For example, `expr //. {a___, 0, 1, b___} :> {a, b}` takes $O(n^2)$ time in the length of the list, when it really could be $O(n)$, if we had better ways of describing and using sequence-based patterns.

What we really need is one or two functions with the same semantics as the `String*` functions, except that they operate on lists of expressions rather than strings of characters.

I do think that `PatternSequence` could be re-used in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Keeping my fingers crossed for future versions then :). Is there any chance the documentation can be expanded a bit on this point? (I searched, but couldn't find anything).

Comment: Solve it elegantly and in O(n) is a old unsolved MMA operation. The string parallel is perfect. +1