# How to ReplaceAll independent of depth?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a big list which in principle can be described as this more compact list :

```
list1 = {{e, {{a, 0.1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 0.5}, {d, 0.7}}, 
    f, {{a, 0.2}, {b, 0.4}, {c, 0.6}, {d, 0.8}}, g, h, i}};
```

I am interested in rewriting to the following :

```
{{e, {"abcd", 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7}, f, {"abcd", 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}, g,
   h, i}}
```

which works well when applying this simple rule:

```
list1 /. {{a, x1_}, {b, x2_}, {c, x3_}, {d, x4_}} -> {"abcd", x1, x2, 
   x3, x4}
```

However when the affected sublists `{a,x1}` to `{d,x4}` are not on the same depth, I have difficulties constructing a rule that works. So for instance:

```
list2 = {{e, {a, 0.1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 0.5}, {d, 0.7}, 
   f, {{a, 0.2}, {b, 0.4}, {c, 0.6}, {d, 0.8}}, g, h, i}}
```

does not give the desired result.

So my questions are:
1. Is there a way to ReplaceAll independent of depth?
2. Is there a more elegant method that does the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Level really has nothing to do with the problem you are experiencing; `ReplaceAll` already works equivalently at all levels, following a [depth-first preorder traversal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121).

Instead your problem is that the section of the expression that you wish to replace is not self-contained in `list2`.  In `list1` it is complete:

```
{{a, 0.1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 0.5}, {d, 0.7}}
```

In `list2` it is a subsequence of a larger expression:

```
{e, {a, 0.1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 0.5}, {d, 0.7}, f, . . .}
```

This is simply not the same structure and it is not matched by your pattern.  I believe the simplest workaround is to add a [`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) to be beginning and end of your pattern:

```
rule =
  {p___, {a, x1_}, {b, x2_}, {c, x3_}, {d, x4_}, q___} :>
    {p, {"abcd", x1, x2, x3, x4}, q};
```

(Note the use of [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html) which is necessary to localize pattern names and which should have been used in your original rule as well.)

And then use [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) to catch all cases:

```
list2 //. rule
```

> ```
> {{e, {"abcd", 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7}, f, {{"abcd", 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}}, g, h, i}}
> ```

This is however terribly inefficient as many different alignments must be tried and the expression is repeatedly scanned.  I am thinking about a better alternative that is sufficiently flexible.

---

The only simple optimization that comes to mind is replace `ReplaceRepeated` with a manual application of `/.` on only the parts of the expression that have not already been scanned.  This should greatly improve performance on long lists as it will prevent the entire expression from being rescanned for every replacement.

```
rule2 = {p___, {a, x1_}, {b, x2_}, {c, x3_}, {d, x4_}, q___} :> 
   Join[{p, {"abcd", x1, x2, x3, x4}}, {q} /. rule2];
```

Note the self-referential use of `rule2`; it is important to keep this Symbol defined for the replacement to work.  Now:

```
list2 /. rule2
```

> ```
> {{e, {"abcd", 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7}, f, {{"abcd", 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}}, g, h, i}}
> ```

Comment: Nice! I tried this approach myself but now see my mistake... I forgot to add a letter to the BlankNullSequence ___ . Darn, I was so close :)

Comment: @MathLind This question/operation comes up so often I really think *Mathematica* needs a simpler syntax for it.  I wish that this would work:  `list2 /. PatternSequence[{a, x1_}, {b, x2_}, {c, x3_}, {d, x4_}] :> {"abcd", x1, x2, x3, x4}`  (It of course doesn't.)

Comment: Hear hear. But alas, [it has good reasons not to work](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54833/5485) ...

Comment: @TeakeNutma I missed that question; thanks for the link!

Comment: @TeakeNutma What Tali wrote: `... when it really could be O(n), if we had better ways of describing and using sequence-based patterns. What we really need is one or two functions with the same semantics as the String* functions ...` is exactly what I am talking about, though on reflection I agree that `PatternSequence` likely plays no role in that.  I have actually converted expressions into strings simply for the sequence handling, which seems indicative of a hole in the language at present.

Answer (score 1):

```
list2 = {{e, {a, 0.1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 0.5}, {d, 0.7}, f, {{a, 0.2}, {b, 0.4}, {c, 0.6}, {d, 0.8}}, g, h, i}};

list2 /.
  {e, head__, f , tail__} :> {e, {head}, f, tail} /.
    {{a, x1_}, {b, x2_}, {c, x3_}, {d, x4_}} :> {"abcd", x1, x2, x3, x4}
```

> {{e, {a, 0.1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 0.5}, {d, 0.7}, f, {"abcd", 0.2, 0.4,
>   0.6, 0.8}, g, h, i}}

Comment: This works very well eldo. Let me metabolize your code a while. BTW how do you make your output yellow like above.

Comment: @MathLind Thanks, but see my comment to Öska's answer :)

Comment: @MathLind The yellow background is because he used the blockquote button in the editor instead of the code sample button.

Comment: @Pickett Thanks, I will apply this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another alternative using `Replace` with `{0, Infinity}` levelspec and it was surprisingly faster than `ReplaceAll` in the other answer.

```
replace = Replace[#, {p___, {a, x1_}, {b, x2_}, {c, x3_}, {d, x4_}, 
      q___} -> {p, {"abcd", x1, x2, x3, x4}, q}, {0, Infinity}] &;
replace[list2]
(* {{e, {"abcd", 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7}, f, {{"abcd", 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}}, 
  g, h, i}} *)
```

---

**Comparing methods**

```
list = Nest[
  Append[List /@ #, 
    Transpose@{{a, b, c, d}, RandomReal[1, 4]}~Prepend~
     RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"]]] &, {}, 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Equal @@ (#@list & /@ {# //. rule &, # /. rule2 &, replace[#] &})
(* True *)
```

---

**Timings**

```
Module[{rule, rule2, replace, listCompare, timings},
 rule = {p___, {a, x1_}, {b, x2_}, {c, x3_}, {d, x4_}, 
    q___} :> {p, {"abcd", x1, x2, x3, x4}, q};
 rule2 = {p___, {a, x1_}, {b, x2_}, {c, x3_}, {d, x4_}, q___} :> 
   Join[{p, {"abcd", x1, x2, x3, x4}}, {q} /. rule2];
 replace = 
  Replace[#, {p___, {a, x1_}, {b, x2_}, {c, x3_}, {d, x4_}, 
      q___} -> {p, {"abcd", x1, x2, x3, x4}, q}, {0, Infinity}] &;
 listCompare = {# //. rule &, # /. rule2 &, replace[#] &};
 timings[n_Integer] := 
  With[{list = 
     Nest[Append[List /@ #, 
        Transpose@{{a, b, c, d}, RandomReal[1, 4]}~Prepend~
         RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"]]] &, {}, n]},
   {n, First@AbsoluteTiming@#@list} & /@ listCompare];
 timings /@ Range[100, 1000, 100] // Transpose // 
  ListLinePlot[#, PlotLegends -> {"rule", "rule2", "replace"}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"Levels", "AbsoluteTiming"}] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I only noticed this answer now.  Interesting claims!  But I am too tired now to dig into it.  Please remind me if I haven't responded in a few days.